# Removing items in a MutableList with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mutablelist

I could have a list like

```
 ["1", "2", "3", ".", "4", "."]
```

After the first occurrence of my delimiter, I want the duplicates removed

In my case, the above list should become

```
 ["1", "2", "3", ".", "4"]
```

I want all duplicates of "." removed after the first occurrence. Whats the best way?

Comment: `list.removeAt(list.indexOfLast { it == "." })`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a temporary MutableSet to easily check if values are duplicates.

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.removeDuplicates(): Boolean {
    val set = mutableSetOf<T>()
    return retainAll { set.add(it) }
}
```

Explanation: `MutableList.retainAll` is a function that removes every item for which the lambda returns false. When you add an item to a Set, it returns false if the item already exists in the set. So the first occurrence of each unique item will return true while subsequent occurrences will return false

---

Edit: It occurred to me that maybe you are interested only in the specific delimiter entry having duplicates. In that case, instead of a Set, I would use just a Boolean to track if it's been found yet. And I use `removeAll` instead of `retainAll` to make it easier to read.

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.removeDuplicatesOf(delimiter: T): Boolean {
    var firstInstanceFound = false
    return removeAll { it == delimiter && firstInstanceFound.also { firstInstanceFound = true } }
}
```

Explanation: `removeAll` will *remove* anything for which the lambda returns true. Due to logical short-circuiting, anything that isn't the delimiter will return false before the part after the `&&` is reached. When the first delimiter is found, `firstInstanceFound` will be false, so the logical statement evaluates to false. The `also` branch is also hit, so `firstInstanceFound` will be true for any subsequent delimiters found.

Comment: Can you explain how it works? I am new to Kotlin and the code looks simple. I can tell a lot is going on

Answer (score 1):

I found two ways. The first is the most 'Java':

```
// Setup values
val list = mutableListOf("1", "2", "3", ".", "4", ".")
val delim = "."

// Check if list is empty
val size = list.size - 1
if (size < 0) return

// Get first delim index
val firstMatch = list.indexOf(delim) + 1
if (firstMatch < 1) return

// Reverse-iterate the list until delim location
for (i in size downTo minOf(firstMatch, size)) {
    if (list[i] == delim) list.removeAt(i)
}

println(list)
```

Here is smaller Kotlin-style solution:

```
val list = mutableListOf("1", "2", "3", ".", "4", ".")
val delim = "."

val firstMatch = list.indexOf(delim)
if (firstMatch < 0) return
val newList = list.filterIndexed { index, s -> s != delim || index == firstMatch }
println(newList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is using `distinct()` function, that returns a list without duplicated values

```
val list = listOf('1', '2', '3', '.', '4', '.')
println(list.distinct()) // [1, 2, 3, ., 4]
```

Comment: I am not looking to remove anything except subsequent "." after the first one

Comment: distinct() function will return a list without duplicates values, so, you will have a list without the subsequent "."  after first one, like you want.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was down-voted. It's not wrong. But it should be noted that this produces a new, separate List instance and doesn't modify the contents of the original MutableList.

Comment: Yeah, totally, there are too many ways to solve this problem. This is with another list instead of modify the existing one

Comment: `distinct()` will remove duplicated numbers too. I got the impression the question was to just remove the duplicated `.` characters.

Answer (score 0):

To remove these apply for loops and add the items in a new list.Steps

First Convert list into mutable list

```
 val list = listOf("1", "2", "3", ".", "4", ".")
 val mutablelist =list.toMutableList()
```

after this apply for loop and storing data in new Outcoming list

```
  val outcominglist= ArrayList<String>()

 for(i in list){
    val item = mutablelist[0]
    mutablelist.removeAt(0)
    if(outcominglist.contains(item)){

    }
    else{
        outcominglist.add(item)
    }
 }
```

To print Outcoming list.

```
print(outcominglist)
```

**Second and the Simplest Method(Use .distinct Method)**

```
 val list = listOf('1', '2', '3', '.', '4', '.')
 val newlist =list.distinct()
 print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Kotlin, you have the advantage of immutable data types and functions without side-effects. Here's how to do it with an immutable list in a function that doesn't expose any state externally, by making use of [`fold()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html):

```
val originalList = listOf("1", "2", "3", ".", "4", ".")

val (filteredList, _) = originalList.fold(
    Pair(emptyList<String>(), false)
) { (newList, found), item ->
    if (item == "." && !found) Pair(newList + item, true)
    else if (item == ".") Pair(newList, true)
    else Pair(newList + item, found)
}

println(filteredList)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, ., 4]
```

`fold()` takes an initial accumulator value, then applies the function for each element of list, updating the accumulator as it goes.

Here we set the accumulator to a `Pair` of an empty list, where we will build up the new list, and a boolean, to track if we've already seen `.`.

For each element of the original list, we return a new pair, adding the item to the new list (if necessary) and updating whether we have already seen `.`. `newList + item` doesn't add the item to the immutable list, it returns a new immutable list with the item appended to it. Because we pass the `Bool` tracking if we've seen `.` as part of the pair to each iteration, there's no need for a temporary variable outside the function to track this.

Finally, because the accumulated value is a Pair, we use [destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) to extract only the accumulated list (the first value) of the pair with `val (filteredList, _) = pair`.

For your list, the returned Pair values will look like this:

1. `([1], false)`
2. `([1, 2], false)`
3. `([1, 2, 3], false)`
4. `([1, 2, 3, .], true)`
5. `([1, 2, 3, ., 4], true)`
6. `([1, 2, 3, ., 4], true)`